# shift an array and insert a new element at given position using memcpy

Tags: c++, position, memcpy, shift

I need to shift the array and insert a new element at given position using `memcpy`.

```
Input: 2, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0

Expected output: 2, 3, 5, 7, 0, 0

Actual output: 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0
```

Is there a mistake in my `memcpy`? (I have to use arrays - not `std::vectors`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int len=0;
    int a[6] = {'\0'};
    a[0]= 2;
    a[1] = 5;
    a[2]= 7;
    len=3;
    int b=0;
    b = 2;
    memcpy(a+2, a+1, b * sizeof(int));
    //memcpy(a+2, a+1, sizeof(int) * (len-1));
    a[1]=3;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        printf("after %d \n", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to be looking at using: `memmove` rather than `memcpy`?

Comment: Operation of memcpy when the regions overlap is not defined.

Comment: Perhaps you should be looking at `std::copy` rather than `memcpy` or `memmove`?

Comment: Added "homework" tag since you *have to use* raw arrays and *need to use* `memcpy`. Those are not sane requirements. Discounting less reasonable possibilities, the only one left is homework.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf This is not homework - it is part of the project at my work. We are comparing perf of linked list vs arrays for random inserts and moves.

Comment: @swap: If your workplace has requirements of using raw arrays and of needing to use `memcpy`, then it's a good idea to silently start looking for a new job, ASAP. Because those are not sane requirements for professional work. They only make sense in an educational setting.

Answer (score 7):

From the manpage for `memcpy`:

> The memory areas should not overlap.  Use memmove(3) if the memory areas do overlap.

And for completeness, from the C99 standard:

> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: That works! Thank you.

This memmove should hold good even if my input is  2, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12 and I insert 3 at position 1, right? assuming I check the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually copying the 5 (`a[1]`)over correctly, but it is writing over the 7 (`a[2]`)

You will need to add another memcpy to copy the 7 entry over first, and THEN you can copy the 5 over.

Since you are technically moving memory, however, I would suggest what Mike Seymour said, and do a memmove:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memmove/